# Gmail shows a wrong number of unread inbox mails

Tags: gmail

I tried to use the code "In:anywhere is:unread" to to a preliminary troubleshooting, but Gmail seemed to still shows that there is one unread mail in my inbox. This happened only after I transferred my old Gmail account to a new one. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Search for `in:inbox is:unread`. That'll find any unread messages in your inbox.

`in:anywhere` searches everywhere, including `spam` and `trash`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only mark blocks of 100 messages at the time. Use browse function to choose different blocks and find your unread message, up to the right. (Ex: "< 1 to 100 of 432 >")

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above but got too many messages in the SPAM filters that Gmail does for you but this search string worked to find the single culprit:

`in:inbox is:unread -label:social -label:promotions`

Comment: Which "above"? Are you referring to the question, or another answer?